# A geometric sequence using one digit

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

Give the first few terms of a geometric<sup>[1]</sup> sequence such that:

> - the sequence is increasing and infinite
> - only one digit is used throughout the sequence
> - the terms are written as base ten decimals and are integers

<sup>[1]</sup><sub>For a geometric sequence, each subsequent term is found by multiplying the previous one by a fixed non-zero number.</sub>

Comment: Do you have a particular sequence in mind that you know exists?

Comment: @AHKieran, yes, one, and replies may be with its first few terms, instead of later terms of the same seq.

Comment: Are you asking for the first few terms because the pattern of only one digit breaks at some point? Because a geometric sequence is uniquely determined by its first term and its common ratio.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this sequence

> $9.999\ldots$
>  $99.999\ldots$
>  $999.999\ldots$
>  $9999.999\ldots$

as each term is

> an integer equal to $10, 100, 1000, 10000$ etc

Comment: appears to fail in the requirement that the terms are integers

Comment: @Penguino these are integers

Comment: This is this most correct answer, since we have to use rounded decimals, or there's only 9 candidate sequences, which are all not geometric.

Comment: @hexonimo Hmmm, I see what you mean.

Comment: Nice. Is that `lateral-thinking`?

Comment: @MatthewWells This isn't rounding, those are real equal signs.

Comment: Are you using `10` as the fixed non-zero integer?

Answer (score 3):

There are infinite of these sequences

All have their geometric factor (not sure about this term) of

> 1x

Example:

> 0, 0, 0, ...
>  5, 5, 5, ...
>  11, 11, 11, ...
>  888, 888, 888, ...
>  ...

Comment: Maybe this is strictly correct but I meant strictly increasing :P

Comment: The "geometric factor" is usually called the common ratio of the sequence, since it is the ratio that any two consecutive terms share.